# Prove that cardinality of $\lvert D \rvert=2^b$ when $D=\{f \mid f:B \to A\} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A,B$ sets and $B$ infinite set , $\lvert A\rvert=a , \lvert B\rvert=b$  and $1<a\leq b$, and let $D=\{f \mid f:B \to A\} $. Prove that $\lvert D\rvert=2^b$.

I know that $\lvert D\rvert=\lvert A\rvert^{\lvert B\rvert}$ and there is a subset of $B$ that has the same cardinality as $A$, but how to prove $\lvert D\rvert=2^b$?

Comment: I am probably missing something but if $B$ is infinite then how is $\mid B\mid=b$?

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa I would assume that $b$ is a cardinal number in this context.

Comment: @AlexProvost ahh, true...:)

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa $b$ can be anything for example א

Comment: yup, true. sorry  :)